# Is android system support multi-release jar?

Tags: java, android, java-9, multi-release-jar

I included a multi-release jar into `app.libs` and call the api in the jar(the api simply print current jdk version). But it didn't work.

Will multi-release jar work in android? How to make it work?

Comment: Android is not Java, it doesn't execute JAR files and it doesn't know anything about "JDK versions". So no: it won't support multi-release jars. Your *build system* might be able to use them and make sense of them in the Android context, but that's not relevant to Android itself.